# JQGrid able to pass ValidateAntiForgeryToken through the main CRUD controls?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, antiforgerytoken

This is my first time setting up a jqGrid, so I implemented a basic grid but am having a rather difficult time passing the __RequestVerificationToken to my controller.

```js
$("#RawMatGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "/RawMat/GetRawMats",
        datatype: 'JSON',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: [
            'Item',
            'Product',
            'Description'
        ],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Item', key: true, index: 'Item', sortable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'Product', key: true, index: 'Product', sortable: true, editable: true },
            { name: 'Description', key: true, index: 'Description', sortable: true, editable: true }
        ],
        pager: "#paging",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        width: 780,
        height: 500,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Raw Mats',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false,
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeateditems: false,
            Id: "0"
            }
    }).navGrid(
        "#paging", {
            edit: true,
            add: true,
            del: false,
            search: true,
            refresh: true
        },
        { },
        { //Add
            zIndex: 100,
            url: '/RawMat/Create',
            mtype: 'POST',
            // This did not work
            editData: { __RequestVerificationToken: jQuery('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },
            processData: "Processing...",
            width: 400,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true
        },
        {});
```

After trying to use the editData field and failing horribly, I have come to ask the experts.

I saw an example of someone being able to pass the token via extraparams within their inline, but the navGrid Add does not allow extraparams from what I read on the documentation site. Has anyone had any experience passing it through the main grid's CRUD controls? Any and all help is definitely appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitively wrong to use `key: true` for more as one column. It break rowids. The id values of rows must have unique value over the HTML page. I recommend you to verify whether `jsonReader` which you use really corresponds the input data which you use. It looks suspected. If you includes 1-2 rows of input data I could help you to correct `jsonReader`.

To send `__RequestVerificationToken` you should define it as function:

```js
editData: { __RequestVerificationToken: function () {
    return $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
}
```

Alternatively you can use `onclickSubmit` callback of form editing to extend the data: just replace `editData` to

```js
onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata, frmoper) {
    return {
        __RequestVerificationToken: $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
    }
}
```

I included unused parameters of `onclickSubmit` callback only to show that `onclickSubmit` allows you to analyse the data which will be sent to the server during editing and to generate the returned data based on the data.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you greatly! I'm not sure what you mean by if I include 1-2 rows of input data? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Dia: You are welcome! You post the code which read data from `"/RawMat/GetRawMats"`. There are many ways to format the data. The `jsonReader` should correspond the format of input data. It could be for example `[{"id": "id1", "Item":"item1", "Product": "Product1", "Description": "Description1"}, {"id": "id2", "Item":"item2", "Product": "Product2", "Description": "Description2"}, ...]` or `{"page": 1, "records": 20: "total": 3, "rows": [{"id": "id1", "cell": ["item1", "Product1", "Description1"]}, ...]}` and many other. Which one you use? Which part of data is unique id of the row item?

Comment: You just saved me!