# Use ValidateAntiForgeryToken with JQGrid in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

In a hybrid asp.net web forms/mvc 5.2.6 application, using JQuery.jqGrid v4.4.4, I'm struggling to discover a way to use the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute on the Controller method that jqGrid posts to when fetching its data.

The grid is read-only.  The "datatype" is "json" and the "mtype" is "POST".  I've tried simply appending the value of the __RequestVerificationToken hidden input to the data that gets posted back to the Controller, but that does not work; the site simply throws a missing antiforgery token exception.

I notice that when one wants to make an $.ajax post of json data to a Controller method one can pass the __RequestVerificationToken in the "headers" parameter.  While the jqGrid makes an $.ajax call behind the scenes, unfortunately it does not have a headers parameter.

I've found examples on SO where one can pass the token via the editData parameter (such as this: [JQGrid able to pass ValidateAntiForgeryToken through the main CRUD controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335741/jqgrid-able-to-pass-validateantiforgerytoken-through-the-main-crud-controls)), but my grid is read-only, and in any case I want to enforce the token when the user enters search criteria and then clicks a button to fill the grid.

Is there any way to use the ValidateAntiForgeryToken when filling a jqgrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `postData` parameter with `__RequestVerificationToken` property defined as the following function:

```
postData: {
    __RequestVerificationToken: function () {
        return jQuery("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
    }
}
```

It will add `__RequestVerificationToken` parameter to all request sent to the server during filling the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Oleg's answer was the correct answer for me, but I also bumbled across this broader-brush solution from https://github.com/VahidN/jqGrid-Samples/blob/master/jqGrid04/jqGrid04/Views/Home/Index.cshtml, which adds the verification token to every ajax POST:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (elm, xhr, s) {
        let securityToken = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
        if (s.type === 'POST' && typeof securityToken != 'undefined') {
            if (s.data.length > 0) {
                s.data += "&__RequestVerificationToken=" + encodeURIComponent(securityToken);
            }
            else {
                s.data = "__RequestVerificationToken=" + encodeURIComponent(securityToken);
            }
        }
    });
```